# End user Google Account not authorized

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a django app running on appengine and would like to attach a cloud sql instance to it. I've set up everything as necessary, and would like to populate the database with a simple

```
manage.py syncdb
```

but the above call gives me a "google.storage.speckle.python.api.rdbms.DatabaseError: 0: End user Google Account not authorized" error

I've set up the cloudsql to allow access to my appenging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong OAuth2 credentials.  Try deleting the credentials .dat file and logging in again.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django#authentication